# "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" + "Origin … is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I'm creating a react app with 'create-react-app', express, cors and mysql in which a user should enter some details in a form which then will be sent to a db. All the existing entries should be shown on the web app.
I tried that locally and everything worked well. The database has been populated and a request has shown the database entries on the web app.

Then i deployed after a 'npm run build' command to my web-hoster (all-inkl.com). Now, the db entries aren't shown and i also can't populate the db anymore.
The Chrome DevTools and Safari Inspector tell me, that it is something with CORS. After some research i know, that the request to the db should come from the same domain, due to CORS policy (and SOP policy?). But i don't know how to fix it.
In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413398/mobile-only-cors-error-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-in) the problem was incorrect db credentials. In my case, I'm pretty sure, that the credentials are correct.

At this code block Chrome throws the corresponding error

```
getBets = _ => {
    fetch("http://www.subdomain.example.de/bets")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => this.setState({bets: response.data}))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
  };
```

## Chrome DevTools Errors:

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

*Access to fetch at 'http://www.subdomain.example.de/test' from origin 'http://subdomain.example.de' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

*TypeError: Failed to fetch*

## Safari Inspector Errors:

*Origin http://subdomain.example.de is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*

*Fetch API cannot load http://www.subdomain.example.de/test due to access control checks.*

*Failed to load resource: Origin http://subdomain.example.de is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin*

*TypeError: Origin http://subdomain.example.de is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin*

Since i don't know which part of the code contains the problem, the whole code is following.

### server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql");

const app = express(); //initialize express

// const PORT = process.env.port;

const SELECT_ALL_BETS_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM markers";

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "http://www.subdomain.example.de",
    user: "***",
    password: "***",
    database: "***"
});

connection.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }
});

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("go to /test to see tests")
});

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    connection.query(SELECT_ALL_BETS_QUERY, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err)
        }
        else {
            return res.json({
                data: results
            })
        }
    })
});

app.get("/test/add", (req, res) => {
    const {name, test, count1, count2, type} = req.query;
    const INSERT_BET = `INSERT INTO markers (name, test, lat, lng, type) VALUES("${name}", "${test}", 99, 88, "test3")`;
    connection.query(INSERT_BET, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            return res.send("succesfully added your test")
        }
    })
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("I'm listening to port 4000")
});
```

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    tests: [],
    test: {
      person_name: "Peter Pan",
      time: "10:17 Uhr"
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTest();
  }

  getTests = _ => {
    fetch("http://www.subdomain.example.de/test")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => this.setState({tests: response.data}))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
  };

  addTest = _ => {
    const { test } = this.state;

    fetch(`http://www.subdomain.example.de/tests/add?name=${test.person_name}&bet=${test.time}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(this.getTests)
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
  };

  renderBets = ({ test_id, name, test}) =>
      <div key={test_id}>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{test}</p>
      </div>;

    render() {
    const { tests, test } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
              {tests.map(this.renderTests)}
              <div>
                <input
                    value={test.person_name}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({test: { ...test, person_name: e.target.value}})}
                />
                <input
                    value={test.time}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({test: { ...test, time: e.target.value}})}
                />
                <button onClick={this.addTest}>Click Me</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

## Information to the boundary conditions of the server

The server ist hosted by *all-inkl.com*. I working with a premium account due to the possibility of ssh. With ssh i installed node.js in the directory of my project. node.js is required because my project ist built up with reactJS.
If any further information due to the server configuration, please ask since i don't know which information are helpful.
I followed the instructions for installing node.js on [this page](http://mamas-blog.de/2017/05/11/all-inkl-com-node-js-und-composer-im-hosting-einrichten/)

In addition, i added the following to the .htaccess-file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

## Edit

I found a helpful (hopefully) webpage [test-cors](https://www.test-cors.org). The test outputs the following without passing any request headers:

```
Fired XHR event: loadstart
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: progress
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: load
XHR status: 200
XHR status text: 
XHR exposed response headers:

cache-control: public, max-age=600
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/html
date: Fri, 02 Aug 2019 17:36:12 GMT
etag: "1rO4KQ"
expires: Fri, 02 Aug 2019 17:46:12 GMT
server: Google Frontend
x-cloud-trace-context: 2c0391d5a5e09665df3f0b243e2b90a6;o=1
```

Does the *XHR status* mean, that CORS is running and that there isn't any error?

Comment: CORS issues are almost always related to the server. I think you should amend your question to add additional information regarding how you're hosting the server.

Comment: in first glance, [`cors()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) usage seems legit to me. client code does not matter, better provide response headers for OPTIONS request instead. probably your code is failing somewhere and non-200 status is returned for OPTIONS.

Comment: *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)* <= That’s the problem you need to fix.

Comment: @sideshowbarker so, it's likely that the server.js doesn't work properly, isn't it? Locally i start the server.js with nodemon. On the server, hosted by _all-inkl.com_, i don't know which command starts the server.js if necessary at all. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @technogeek1995 I added some information regarding the server. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: I tried some different approaches. I think i get closer to the solution.
If i delete the _www_ in front of the fetch-url, the cors error disappears.
And if i delete the directory after the slash (_/test_) i only get an error regarding json --> _SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0_. Even though, the behavior seems very weird to me

Comment: I think what's actually happening is that your server is failing to start up/crashing on the endpoint you're calling. I'm not familiar with all-inkl.com, but with Azure App Services (probably pretty similar), your code is not exposed to the outside world directly. Instead, it's proxied through their server which has access to the outside world. Typically, if it fails to get a response, the proxy will respond with a 404 or 500. However, if you haven't configured CORS on your proxy, you're likely getting a CORS issue before you ever get the 404 or 500. I would try to configure CORS on all-inkl.

Comment: I tried to look at all-inkl.com's support documentation to configure CORS, but it's in German so I'm not much help looking for support documentation in German. However, you might be able to reach out to their support and ask them to do it for you. Basically, you need to provide them with the URL of where your React App (SPA) is hosted so they can permit sending proxy responses to that URL. They may also be able to turn off CORS on the proxy which isn't likely a big deal since you're also doing it with your server.

Comment: @technogeek1995 I contacted all-inkl.com. I will get back to you when i know more.

Comment: @technogeek1995 i contacted the customer service. They told me, that changes in the .htaccess-file doesn't have any affect. They have to edit something called _VHOST_. I told them, to add the lines of code mentioned in section _Information to the boundary conditions of the server_ to the VHOST. But nothing changed.

Comment: Have you restarted the server? Seems like something on the server still isn't configured correctly. In fact, I would look at switching providers to Amazon, Google, or Azure if all-inkl can't get it resolved. It's pretty easy to get node/react up and running on those service providers.

Comment: It popped up a new idea what the problem could be. During testing the webapp locally, i started a node server as _nodemon server.js_. But on the hosted server, I'm not able to do that. Could it be possible, that the file has to be executed by some command? And what could it look like? IMO, the server.js serves the URL's. If the server.js isn't running, it would make sense that i get a 404 error.

Comment: @technogeek1995 ok, I'm on the right track then. I will contact them again regarding the server.js file. Many thanks for your help. If they can't solve it, I will change the provider.

Comment: ok, the problem is, that the provider doesn't allow node on their servers. A lot of whirl for nothing. I deployed my webapp to an EC2 instance on AWS. Now, everything works fine. Thanks a lot to all of you.

Answer (score -1):

You might try to enable CORS in you `fetch` request, because it's not enabled by default:

```
getBets = _ => {
    fetch("http://www.subdomain.example.de/bets", { mode: 'cors' })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => this.setState({bets: response.data}))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
};
```

Comment: I added the code to enable CORS, but with no success. Still the same error.